# Build out a custom modal view

Tags: objective-c, ipad, modalviewcontroller

I am looking to build out a custom modal view for an ipad app. I thought I could simply use the built in modal view controller ability and then customize it's appearance to fit my designs. Turns out that's not true. Any good advice or documentation on how I would go about doing so. My Objective-C knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Turns out that's not true.

Turns out it's not true that that's not true.

Your job is do create a custom view controller and design its view in any way you want. Then present it modally with `presentModalViewController:animated:`afte setting its `modalPresentationStyle` according to your needs.

Comment: I didn't really think of it that way. I was too fixated on using built in modal styles. The growing pains of learning a new process I suppose. Appreciate the help!

Comment: How to create a custom view controller? Any tutorials out there?

Comment: @nishantcm: Just subclass `UIViewController`.